# Problems with asynchronous functions with TcpListener and TcpClient, function not waiting on await keyword

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am new to asynchronous socket programming, and I am having problems with my asynchronous functions.

I am trying to create a chat program that uses Windows Forms for the client, and a console application for the server.

Here is the code for handling connections on my server:

```
public async void StartServer()
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(_ip, _port);
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Server is running on IP: {0} Port: {1}", _ip.ToString(), _port);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            HandleConnections(client);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
private async void HandleConnections(TcpClient client)
{
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    string message = null;
    int x;
    while(stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        x = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        message += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
    }
    message = message.Replace('\0', ' ');
    message = message.Trim();
    Console.WriteLine("Message Recieved: " + message);
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    stream.Close();
}
```

And here is the code for the client program connecting to the server:

```
private async void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(IPInput.Text);
    client = new TcpClient();
    await client.ConnectAsync(address, 12345);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    string message = UsernameInput.Text + " Connected!";
    Task<int> sendTask = SendMessage(stream, message);
    int sendComp = await sendTask;
    Task<string> recieveTask = RecieveMessage(stream);
    string recieved = await recieveTask;
    stream.Close();
    ChatText.AppendText(recieved);
}
private async Task<int> SendMessage(NetworkStream stream, string message)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message + "\r\n");
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return 1;
}
private async Task<string> RecieveMessage(NetworkStream stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    string message = null;
    int x;
    while (stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        x = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        message += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
    }
    return message;
}
```

The first problem that I am having is when I run the client program and click the ConnectButton, the message gets sent to the server program which outputs `Message Recieved: user Connected!`, but then the client program encounters a null reference exception on the line `ChatText.AppendText(recieved);` saying that the `recieved` variable is null. It seems that the line `string recieved = await recieveTask;` is not waiting for the task to finish executing, and it jumps to the next line without assigning a value to `recieved`. If I put a breakpoint at the top of the `private async Task<string> RecieveMessage(NetworkStream stream)` function and step through it, then the `recieved` variable gets it's value and the code will complete successfully, but without the breakpoint I get the null reference exception.

The next issue that I am having, is if I leave the server running and open the client again and try connecting, the server gets a null reference exception on the line `message = message.Replace('\0', ' ');`. The first time I run with the client, the server receives the message successfully, but the second time, it doesn't get any data from the stream and leaves the variable null, resulting in a null reference exception.

I apologize if my code is garbage, I have been reading the MSDN documentation for hours and am unable to come up with a solution, and I feel like I am doing this completely wrong. So my questions are as follows:

What is causing these errors that I am encountering? And am I approaching this problem the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your issues are not related to asynchronous functions, and actually both issues are because of the same problem:

```
while (stream.DataAvailable)
{
    // read stream here
}
```

If data is not *yet* available to read from the stream - both of your ReceiveMessage and HandleConnections functions just skip reading stream at all. What you should do instead (in your case) is:

```
do
{
    // read your stream here
} while (stream.DataAvailable);
```

Then first Read (or ReadAsync) will wait until first data chunk arrives, and only after first chunk will check if more data is already available.

Also note that you use large buffer (256 bytes) while client\server send short messages (like "Client received: xxx"), which means most of the buffer is empty and when you convert it to string via Encoding.ASCII.GetString - you get a lot of whitespace at the end ("Client received: xxx     ...   ").

Comment: Wow, I didn't think something as simple as changing my while loop to a do while would fix the issue. Thank you so much. I feel kind of stupid now because of how long I was stuck with this issue.

Comment: @PhantomWhiskers - a separate issue which is about to bite you - you *really* need to pay attention to the value that is *returned* from `ReadAsync`. It tells you *how many* bytes have been received. A lot of your code seems to assume that you'll have received exactly as many bytes as you asked for, and that's not guaranteed. Bear in mind that TCP's abstraction is a stream of bytes, not *messages*. If you want to send and receive messages, it's up to you to implement that atop TCP, or move to a higher level abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like a problem with `async`/`await` so much as an issue with your TCP streams.

You don't appear to be actually waiting for a response. `SendMessage` writes the server, then `RecieveMessage` expects a response to already be in the stream.

If `stream.DataAvailable` is false when you hit the `while` loop for the first time, `message` will remain `null`.

You need some way to wait for there to be data in the stream before you attempt to read from it.

Comment: I changed my while loops to do while loops like the answer above suggested, and it fixed my issue. Thank you for the response.